# matlab adjacency list to adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

How to convert adjacency list to adjacency matrix via matab

For example: Here is the adjacency list(undirected), the third column is the weight.

1  2  3
1  3  4
1  4  5
2  3  4
2  5  8
2  4  7

++++++++++++++++++++++

that should be converted to:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  

1     0  4  5  0   
2  3     4  7  8  
3  4  7     0  0  
4  0  7  0     0  
5  0  8  0  0
```

Comment: Why isn't the diagonal zero? And if you consider undirected connections, the matrix has to be symmetric.

Comment: I reformatted your matrix... is that what you were after? Why isn't it symmetrical?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix. Let `rows` be the first column, `cols` the second, and `s` the weight.

```
A = sparse([rows; cols],[cols; rows],[s; s]);
```

If you want to see the matrix. use `full()`.

**UPDATE:**

I made the answer a bit simpler (everything in one line, instead of adding the transposed, and included explanations, as requested:

```
list = [1 2 3
1 3 4
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 5 8
2 4 7];

rows = list(:,1)
cols = list(:,2)
s = list(:,3)
```

Now, `rows`, `cols` and `s` contains the needed information. Sparse matrices need three vectors. Each row of the two first vectors, `rows` and `cols` is the index of the value given in the same row of `s` (which is the weight).

The sparse command assigns the value `s(k)` to the matrix element `adj_mat(rows(k),cols(k))`.

Since an adjacency matrix is symmetric, `A(row,col) = A(col,row)`. Instead of doing `[rows; cols]`, it is possible to first create the upper triangular matrix, and then add the transposed matrix to complete the symmetric matrix.

```
A = sparse([rows; cols],[cols; rows],[s; s]);    
full(A)

A = 
   0   3   4   5   0
   3   0   4   7   8
   4   4   0   0   0
   5   7   0   0   0
   0   8   0   0   0
```

Comment: could you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what your'e asking. Is this right?

```
list = [1 2 3
1 3 4
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 5 8
2 4 7];


matrix = zeros(max(max(list(:, 1:2))));  %// Or just zeros(5) if you know you want a 5x5 result

matrix(sub2ind(size(matrix), list(:,1), list(:,2))) = list(:,3);  %// Populate the upper half
matrix = matrix + matrix'  %'// Find the lower half via symmetry

matrix =

   0   3   4   5   0
   3   0   4   7   8
   4   4   0   0   0
   5   7   0   0   0
   0   8   0   0   0
```