# How to create a weighted adjacency matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dijkstra, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix, haversine

I have a dataset in the following format:

```
UID     Lat    Long   LocID

u1      lt1    lg1    l1

u1      lt2    lg2    l2

u1      lt3    lg3    l3

u2      lt4    lg4    l4

u3      lt1    lg1    l1

u3      lt4    lg4    l4
```

From here I need to generate a LocID-LocID un-directed graph. For this I need a weighted matrix in the following format.

```
    0           d(l1,l2)        0           0

  d(l2,1)          0         d(l2,l3)    d(l2,l4)

    0           d(l3,l2)        0           0

  d(l4,l1)      d(l4,l2)        0           0
```

Since, user-u1 is present at locations l1, l2 and l3, hence i consider them as visible edges in the graph. And hence, there exists edge from l1 -> l2 and l2->l3. From the given example, there exists 4 edges.

```
l1 -> l2 ; l2->l3 [For user u1]
l2->l4 [For user u2]
l1 -> l4 [For user u3]
```

here weight of each edge between two LocID is computed from the given Latitude and Longitude information. Like, d(l1,l2) = distance between LocID-1 and LocID-1 
                            = distance between (lt1,lg1) and (lt2,lg2)

Distance calculation can be done by using haversine formula. So, that is not a problem.
I need to perform this task in matlab. Can anyone please help me....
thanks in advance....

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is the question how to create a matrix with such a pattern? I don't understand the pattern. Is the distance already defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [matlab adjacency list to adjacency matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295931/matlab-adjacency-list-to-adjacency-matrix)

Comment: edit the question for more details...

Comment: Much clearer now, but still some questions. Why is your distance matrix not symmetric? There is `d(l4,l1)` but not `d(l1,l4)`. Where in your data do you get this information: `l2->l4 [For user u2]`?. In which format is the data provided? `d(l2,1)` is obviously a typo. What is `d`? Is it already defined?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/pdist.html) function in the statistics toolbox.

It calculates distances between points with different distance measures, also custom functions are allowed (as handles).

Comment: Thank for your suggestions. But, i am not concerned about the distance calculation. I need the weighted adjacency matrix.

Comment: That is exactly what pdist hands you. My point is indeed that it can handle any distance metric you'd want to plug in.